# catkin_make fedora hang and does not produce executable

Tags: ros, catkin-make, pcl, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

I'm using the [rosrpm](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/228) for fedora version of ROS and I have two problem.

First : each time I'm trying to compile a package using pcl, catkin_make hang at some point and just never stop and I have to close everything. I don't know why it does that and it's very annoying as I want to use a Xtion. Thus I don't know what information to give but if someone is willing to help me with that, I will be happy to give any kind of information.

Second : I'm trying to compile a very small project named randomly `bouboum` the thing is when I catkin_make bouboum, the only executable I'm asking is not made.
Here are the CMakeList, and the program :

CMakeListe :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bouboum)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  roscpp
)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES bouboum
  CATKIN_DEPENDS pcl_conversions roscpp
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(test src/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

And my program :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Stalker");
    ros::NodeHandle my_node;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);

}
```

Nothing very complicated it was just to test the hanging problem named above.

The thing is it find the good `test.cpp` file since if I change the name in the add_executable command, catkin_make complain about it. I just have nothing happening and I can't understand why.
I created my package using `catkin_make_pkg bouboum pcl_conversions roscpp`

Any help on the matter will be more than appreciated !!

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156301/catkin_make-fedora-hang-and-does-not-produce-executable/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-22**:
Are you sure it isn't placing your test executable somewhere in the build or devel directories?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-04-22**:
I looked in /devel/lib because it's usually paced there and I didn't even found a bouboum folder. I'll check better tonight.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-23**:
The catkin_make output should have a line for each cpp file and binary that it compiles; you should make sure that you test executable is included there. You may have to touch your test.cpp file to trigger a rebuild.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-04-23**:
There is no line printed by catkin_make for any executable even if I change test.cpp. I guess I did something wrong in the makefile or during the package creation. All the other ones works now so must be my fault there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While catkin_make is stuck, try looking for processes that are running and look stuck. I would try running a graphical process monitor or top, and also running something like `ps auxwwwf` to display the process tree, and look for leaves in the process tree which might be blocking the parent process.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-04-22**:
Such a good advice. I used top nd it said that a process kswapd0 was using all the CPU... So if ever someone got the same kind of problem it is because you didn't mount the swap. Thus my system had no swap and I had to manually change fstab... I know, I'm an idiot =P.